# Evaluation of the results of hiererchical clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have used `hclust` function from R for the hierarchical clustering of vectors which are already labeled.

```
dissimilarity <- 1 - cor(data)
distance <- as.dist(dissimilarity)
plot(hclust(distance),  main="Dissimilarity = 1 - Correlation", xlab="")
```

Now I want to evaluate if the vectors with the same label are clustered in the same group. However, I don't know how to find the optimal cutting points in the deprogram. Is there a package for it?

Comment: Why do you want to select the 'best' clustering solution based on some "internal" clustering criterion as long as you've got an external criterion (the labels)? I'm not saying you are wrong... Just _why_?

Comment: @ttnphns We have several cells, and we know what tissue each cell belong to (label). Now we also have some measurements for each cell, and we want to see if we cluster cells using these measures, do we get cells of the same type in the same group?

Comment: I implied that you may choose that clustering solution (level) which is associated most high with your classes (labels). But if you prefer to rely on an internal criterion first - then look at `nbclust` R package; it has a lot of such criterions to compute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `silhouette` in the R package `cluster`

`s=NULL
for(i in 2:10){
   k=cutree(hclust(dist(data),method="ward.D"),i)
   s[i]=summary(silhouette(k,dist(data)))$si.summary[3]
}`

The highest value of s gives you the optimal number of cluster. 
 I suggested moreover to use the method `ward.D` in the hierarchical clustering and to try as well the `KODAMA` package to perform your clustering analysis.

https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/doi/10.1093/bioinformatics/btw705/2667156/KODAMA-an-R-package-for-knowledge-discovery-and#.WE3eq5s-d24